# AWS Create EKS cluster permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm creating an EKS cluster with a user with this permission:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/aws-service-role/eks.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "eks"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/cluster-role-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm doing this in the IAM tool, and the user can go through the console creation screens, and on the final one I get:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::xx:user/xxxx is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:xx:cluster/xxxx with an explicit deny
```

Seems to me the first statement should give the user the permission that's needed, can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Error message says "with an explicit deny", which means either (1) there's a conflicting policy attached to the user, (2) there's a permission boundary set up on the user or (3)  there's a service control policy in your organization that blocks the action.